# Set up apache2 authentication but not for some page

Tags: authentication, localhost

I want to set up apache2 authentication for http://127.0.0.1/ but not for http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin. Is it possible? This is my current `000-default.conf` setting for authentication:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Content"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know maybe not exactly what you asked but it does more or less what you want:

You could instead use a redirect in 
`/var/www/HTML/index.php`

Like

```
<?php
header ("Location: /save/index.php");
?>
```

which leads to a subfolder like e.g. 
`/var/www/html/save/index.php`. 
And than require password only for this subfolder

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/save">      
  AuthType Basic 
  AuthName  "Restricted Content"    
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user 
</Directory>
```

Note: Make sure you only have `/var/www/html/index.php` and no `var/www/html/index.html`.

And of course if your mainpage does not use php at all it may also redirect to html

```
<?php
header("Location: /save/index.html");
?>
```